# Concatenation of String and Control in VB

Tags: html, vb.net, string-concatenation, skype

I am having an issue integrating Skype html codes with my .vb tool to edit the mood profile.

```
  Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Skype.CurrentUserProfile.RichMoodText = "<spinner></spinner>" & TextBox2 & "<spinner></spinner>"

End Sub
```

Although this works with the other html codes, it refuses to work for the spinner tag, as well as the blink tag. 
I have tried replacing the & with + to no avail. Here is the error I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30452 Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and 'TextBox'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

& is used to join two strings together. TextBox2 is the name of a textbox control and the control cannot be joined to a string.

Try using the text property of the control instead

```
Skype.CurrentUserProfile.RichMoodText = "<spinner></spinner>" & TextBox2.Text & "<spinner></spinner>"
```

Comment: OH MY GOD YES. Completely forgot about this LOL

Comment: Glad I could help please mark the answer as correct by pressing the tick